# Can MSAL handle access tokens issued by my own web api?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I would like to use Azure for authentication, but have access tokens provided by my own .net web api. Can msal be configured to call my web api's endpoints instead of azures to manage the lifecycle of the access token?

In a perfect world, I could use acquireTokenSilent the same way I would for azure, but for my own web api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. You'll need to register a custom scope in the Azure Portal for your resource and API, configure your API to require an access token with the right resource and scopes (as registered in the portal), and then provide that scope to MSAL when you call `acquireTokenSilent` or similar APIs.

Comment: ahh I see. Let me try this out and get back to you. Thanks!